# Npm install error: Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path)

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to install a Node.js app doing `npm install` but I'm receiving errors and I don't know how to resolve:

Node -> v8.11.1

Npm  -> 5.6.0

```
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received { url: 'https://raw.github.com/imagemin/gifsicle-bin/v0.1.7/vendor/osx/gifsicle',
  name: 'gifsicle',
  os: 'darwin' }

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received { url: 'https://raw.github.com/imagemin/jpegtran-bin/v0.2.8/vendor/osx/jpegtran',
  name: 'jpegtran',
  os: 'darwin' }

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received { url: 'https://raw.github.com/imagemin/optipng-bin/v0.3.11/vendor/osx/optipng',
  name: 'optipng',
  os: 'darwin' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with double quotation marks, surrounding everything with "" not ''.

Comment: You mean in the package.json?